# Map's InfoWindow won't update to Firebase addValueEventListener

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to get data from Firebase and display this data inside a customized InfoWindow. Here's my code:

```
    map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter(){
        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

            View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window, null);
            final TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            final TextView tv2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

                nRef = new Firebase("https://mydatabase-98057.firebaseio.com/Object");
                nRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        System.out.println("hello : "+dataSnapshot.toString());
                        tv.setText("Spots available : "+dataSnapshot.toString());
                        tv2.setText("Spots available : "+dataSnapshot.toString());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

                    }
                });

            return v;
        }
    });
```

This code is inside the void `onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)` method.

The thing is the System.out.println() displays the data as it should be from Firebase, but the TextViews do not display it, the only text they show is "TextView" which is by default (it means that the text does not change to the new information I'm getting from the database, it's like setText did not run or something).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is caused by `InfoWindow` not being a "live view" and the asynchronous nature of fetching data from Firebase.  The documentation for [InfoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows#custom_info_windows) states:

> Note: The info window that is drawn is not a live view. The view is
>   rendered as an image (using View.draw(Canvas)) at the time it is
>   returned. This means that any subsequent changes to the view will not
>   be reflected by the info window on the map. To update the info window
>   later (for example, after an image has loaded), call showInfoWindow().

In your case, the view is rendered before `onDataChange()` runs and sets the contents of the `TextViews`.  Try following the suggestion in the documentation and call `showInfoWindow()` inside `onDataChange()`:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    System.out.println("hello : "+dataSnapshot.toString());
    tv.setText("Spots available : "+dataSnapshot.toString());
    tv2.setText("Spots available : "+dataSnapshot.toString());
    marker.showInfoWindow(); // <== ADD THIS
}
```

You probably will also need make `marker` final: `getInfoContents(final Marker marker)`.